# How create a file inside WEB-INF folder from servlet?

Tags: servlets

I am new to servlet world.. I want create a file inside WEB-INF (or WEB-INF/some_folder) folder from servlet. and this should be done at server-startup. Please let me know how can it be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the answer, if working vote it

Comment: Note that in general, this is a bad idea: if you're deploying a war file you likely will not have write access to directories inside the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point:** you can access files from servlets but cant access them from web container

```
String filename = "/WEB-INF/somefile.xml" ;
ServletContext context = this.getServlet().getServletContext();
String pathname =context.getRealPath(filename);
```